# Calculate work and vacation slots - Java & Hibernate

Tags: java, algorithm, spring, hibernate

I have a requirement to calculate the working/vacation slots for employees in my application.

A Vacation has a startDate and an endDate. The user can supply a period of time and a report must be generated with the work and vacation slots for a user in that period.

E.g. a user has vacation from 3.02.2013 - 4.02.2013 and the period to search with is 1.02.2013 - 28.02.2013.

The report should look like this:

- 1-2.02.2013 - Work
- 3-4.02.2013 - Vacation
- 5-28.02.2013 - Work

I am not sure how to do this in an efficient way. My DAO method for getting the vacations in the period is the following:

```
public List<VacationRequest> getVacationsInPeriodForUser(Long userId,
        Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    List<VacationRequest> requests = getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "select req from VacationRequest req left join fetch req.vacationType where req.requestState.description = 'APPROVED' and req.user.id= ? and req.startDate >= ? and req.endDate <= ?")
            .setParameter(0, userId).setParameter(1, startDate)
            .setParameter(2, endDate).list();

    return requests;
}
```

But this does not work in the case that the user is in vacation the whole supplied period. For example, if the search period is 3.02.2013 - 4.02.2013 in the example above.

Can anyone suggest how to calculate these slots in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test :
req.startDate < endDate && req.endDate > startDate

You're testing req.startDate > startdate && req.endDate < endDate, which eliminate periods that start before and end after your request bound.

EDIT : assuming that you check that the startDates are always before the endDates

your code becomes

```
public List<VacationRequest> getVacationsInPeriodForUser(Long userId,
        Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    List<VacationRequest> requests = getSessionFactory()
        .getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(
                "select req from VacationRequest req left join fetch req.vacationType where req.requestState.description = 'APPROVED' and req.user.id= ? and req.startDate <= ? and req.endDate >= ?")
        .setParameter(0, userId).setParameter(1, enDate)
        .setParameter(2, startDate).list();

return requests;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in the example I gave, the req.startDate is 3.02.2013 which is > 01.02.2013 which is the startDate.

Comment: SO that's why you DON't compare req.startDate with startDate, but with ENDDATE.
In your example, you will have 3.02 < 28.02 and 4.02 > 01.02, therefore you will get your period.
Write some unit tests, you see this will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your method works. But I'm also struggling with calculating the work slots from the period in the "corner" cases.

Comment: Try to figure an algorithm, this shouldn't be too difficult. For instance, you can loop on every days of your period and check if it is in a vacation time, or sort the vacations, and then build periods of time beginning at an endDate of a vacation and ending at a startDate of the next one...